# Auto update issue

Tags: bug, status-norepro, questions, live-refresh

When ever I used to browse a particular tag ([python](/questions/tagged/python) specifically), the 'newest' question tab would auto update for me. It would say, you "5 new questions" and I'd click on it and it would populate the new questions.

That feature is no longer working for me. I have to refresh the page to get new questions. I'm using Firefox in Mint Linux. It did work before in this same environment, it just stopped working recently. I think yesterday. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you been having connection problems recently?  If it has intermittent connection issues it'll stop trying to update.  It's also possible you have a proxy/firewall preventing the type of connection needed for SO to push content to you.  I know that for me it doesn't always work on certain machines, so it's possibly not an issue on SO's end.

Comment: Hmm... I don't recall any connectivity issues. I'm accessing it here at my office. If it was a firewall issue, would it not have surfaced before?

Comment: It's possible that something changed yesterday in how your network was configured, or it could have just been an unusually high traffic day at the office, etc.  It's just a theory.

Comment: So I tired on firebug to watch the AJAX calls and I'm getting 3 errors:

NetworkError: 502 Bad Gateway - http://sockets-se.or.stackexchange.com/
Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at ws://sockets-se.or.stackexchange.com/.
Error: useless setTimeout call (missing quotes around argument?)

I don't know if that helps any or not.

Comment: as a note the stackoverflow CDN appears to be down. http://isup.me/cdn.sstatic.com

Comment: Is this still happening?

Comment: Yes. I'm still getting the same errors i posted above.

Comment: Can you confirm the version of Mint and Firefox? Using latest FF on Windows doesn't exhibit the issue.

Comment: Linux Mint 12 Lisa / Firefox 18

Comment: Are you logged in when this happens or not?

Comment: Yes I am logged in

Comment: Running Mint with latest FF, when logged in, I can't reproduce. Are you still getting 502s as described in your [comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165857/auto-update-issue#comment484729_165857)?

Comment: @Oded I am still getting the 502s. It doesn't seem to be working in chrome either for me.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I checked out the link you sent. Which prompted me to check chrome which doesn't work either. I went to the link they put in the answer to that question http://websocketstest.com/ and it says websockets supported under the environment section. The websockets (port 80) and websockets (port 8080) sections say I'm disconnected though. All the other sections have green check marks and say I'm connected. Don't know if that means anything.

Comment: It sounds like these ports are blocked - either by the sys admins where you are or the ISP (or both).

Comment: I accept the wisdom of the masses. I wish I knew who to talk to here at my office about this. One final question then. For the 502 Bad Gateway error. It says its for http://sockets.ny.stackexchange.com/ when I check this address at isup.me it says its not just me.